# Parentheses and square brackets contextually in small caps

Tags: xetex, fontspec, brackets, small-caps

In a book publication I use references in parentheses with an open type font. The references are set in small caps (both letters and numbers):

```
% xelatex xetex 0.9999 texlive 2013 windows
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
Numbers=OldStyle,
]{TeX Gyre Pagella}  % to be replaced by a font which supports small caps brackets
\begin{document}

Text (\textsc{ref.} 1.1) text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the parentheses (round or square) around the reference to be set into small caps contextually. What would be the usual way how to do it in latex? Thank you in advance.

Update: The font I use for the publication does support alternate "small caps" brackets, but I still search for a convenient contextual way how to set it so in latex contextually without having to reformat the references:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I can tell, parentheses have the same size in small caps.

Comment: Not a recommendation, but I had a problem similar: with Latin Modern, the numbers are not “small” and don't fit well with lowercase small caps. My “wrong solution”: scale all down (easy wit `l3tl` from LaTeX3). May be, as a last option (if you don't find a font that suit your needs), you can make a latex command to scale all.

Comment: @egreg -- "small caps" usually means "caps and small caps", with the regular caps the same size as the comparable roman font.  hence it's logical that the punctuation be the "normal" size, even if it looks out of place sometimes.  take a look at this discussion in typophile: "[Apostrophe in Small Caps](http://typophile.com/node/65446)".

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know the reason why parentheses are full height also in small caps fonts. Good typography is also choosing the right fonts (shape/weight/whatnot) according to what the document needs. In this case, I would recommend *not* using small caps or avoiding the parentheses for this particular usage.

Comment: @egreg I updated an image of the case with a font I use. There are actually two questions, the first one considering tex if it can set those small caps brackets contextually in a simple way -- I can not do so by simple \textsc{()} --, and the second question going further and considering typography, probably not in the right place: If there is punctuation included in the font, would it be recommendable to combine this punctuation (brackets) with small caps letters and old style numbers in this way? Thank you.

Comment: Well, TeX is not clairvoyant, so it can't know whether a `(` is followed by text in small caps. How do you get the short parentheses?

Comment: Contextually sensitive is the wrong approach, I think.  It would need to be far too clever unless you only used it in very tightly controlled scenarios, and, in that case, you don't really need contextually sensitive ones.  I think that the "correct" approach would be to *abstract* from the text and create a command for this kind of text; if we want 'small parentheses', then let's make a command that you use like so: `\cssc{<text (with more text)>`.  Then you can do all kinds of clever typographical things in it, say: 'small' question marks, exclamation marks, lowered apostrophe's, etc., etc.

Comment: @jon In your most recent comment, you talk about making a separate macro for the job.  How is what you envision in any way different than, for example, `\small`?  I'm not being facetious, but just trying to understand what sort of logic this macro is supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- Well, I certainly don't think it needs to do anything fancier than `\small` (or whatever).  It is just a question of using semantic markup for often used elements in the text.  If I constantly need to refer to (say) book titles, which require emphasis compared to regular text, I don't use `\emph{<book title>}` in my document, but define and use a command like `\btitle{<book title>}`. For the small parentheses, I'd rather define and use `\cssc{<text>}` than `{\small (\textsc{text})}` or whatever.  My main point was that contextually clever parens makes good markup harder.

Answer (score 8):

The discussion at [github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/166](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/166) is relevant to this question.

By all means avoid the suggestion to create a macro with `\small`, just as you would avoid faked small caps. The font itself needs to provide small cap parentheses.

I’ve just tested several dozen fonts, mostly commercial.

Most with the `case` feature use it to produce parentheses which are no smaller than normal, but which sit higher; such parentheses are appropriate around capitals, because they aren’t embracing non-existent descenders, but they’re inappropriate around small caps.

Of the fonts with small cap parentheses, most require no special handling. Simply ensure that the parentheses are inside the `\textsc{}`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cartier Book Pro}
\begin{document}
Text (\textsc{ref.}~1.1) text.

Text \textsc{(ref.~1.1)} text.
\end{document}
```

[image: result with Cartier]

Other fonts which behave similarly are Agmena Pro, Albertan Pro, Augustin, Calluna, Le Monde Livre Classic, Livory, and Maiola PE. Numbers will be affected as well if a font has small cap figures (e.g., Jannon 10 Pro and Neacademia Latin).

Some fonts require turning on the `c2sc` feature.  Here I’ve defined a macro, `\ucsc{}` (for “uppercase small caps”) to make that easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate,Numbers=OldStyle]{Junicode}
\def\ucsc#1{{\addfontfeature{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}
\begin{document}
Text \textsc{(ref.~1.1)} text.

Text \ucsc{(REF.~1.1)} text.
\end{document}
```

[image: output with Junicode]

Other fonts which behave like this are AngiePro, Louize NP, and Satyr.

In short, inspect each font closely. And it’s probably a good idea to check whether each behaves as before whenever you update `fontspec`.